# How to make smoother 2d maps out of a huge (Mbs-scale) .txt file?

Tags: matplotlib, contour, colorbar

I have a `.txt` file that contains five columns of data in which columns 1 and 2 correspond to projected distance along dimension 1 and 2 (pixel scale of 0.50) and then columns 3, 4 and 5 are values of an arbitrary (otherwise unknown) function in projections 0 "z", 1 "x" and 2 "y" respectively. (Original file is ~1e6 rows long but here is a small version of it that I managed to upload: [m11q.txt](http://pastebin.com/6Tj9LHvH)) I would like to transform this `.txt` table into actual 2d maps in which the color strength of each pixel would correspond to the magnitude of the function in that pixel. This means that I would have three planes xy, yz and xz in which each pixel is filled with a color.

My values for columns 3,4 and 5 are mostly zero with few of them on the order of $10^{14}$ to $10^{21}$. I am interested in having three contour levels. Let's say if the function value is smaller than $10^{14}$, the color should be black, if the function value is between $10^{14}$ and $10^{15.5}$, the color should be yellow, and if the function value is between $10^{15.5}$ and $10^{17}$, the color should be orange, if the function value is between $10^{17}$ and $10^{20.3}$, the color should be red and finally if above $10^{20.3}$ the color should be blue. In other words, my 2d map is in fact a set of 5 contour plots that are produced out of `.txt` table.
Here is my original version of the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.interpolate
import matplotlib.figure as fig
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import matplotlib.colorbar as cb
import matplotlib.ticker as tk 
import pylab as pl

x, y, covering_fraction_z, covering_fraction_x, covering_fraction_y = np.genfromtxt(r'm11q.txt', unpack=True)


nInterp = 4000
xi, yi = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), nInterp), np.linspace(y.min(), y.max(), nInterp)
xi, yi = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)

z0 = scipy.interpolate.griddata((x, y), covering_fraction_z, (xi, yi), method='nearest')
z1 = scipy.interpolate.griddata((x, y), covering_fraction_x, (xi, yi), method='nearest')
z2 = scipy.interpolate.griddata((x, y), covering_fraction_y, (xi, yi), method='nearest')

LAF_covering_fraction_XY = np.count_nonzero((np.power(10, 14) <= z0) & (z0 < np.power(10, 17))) * 1.0 / z0.size
LAF_covering_fraction_YZ = np.count_nonzero((np.power(10, 14) <= z1) & (z1 < np.power(10, 17))) * 1.0 / z1.size
LAF_covering_fraction_XZ = np.count_nonzero((np.power(10, 14) <= z2) & (z2 < np.power(10, 17))) * 1.0 / z2.size
LAF = np.sqrt(np.power(LAF_covering_fraction_XY, 2)+np.power(LAF_covering_fraction_YZ, 2)+np.power(LAF_covering_fraction_XZ, 2))/np.sqrt(3)
LAF_sigma = max([abs(LAF-LAF_covering_fraction_XY),abs(LAF-LAF_covering_fraction_YZ),abs(LAF-LAF_covering_fraction_XZ)])
LLS_covering_fraction_XY = np.count_nonzero((np.power(10, 17) <= z0) & (z0 < np.power(10, 20.3))) * 1.0 / z0.size
LLS_covering_fraction_YZ = np.count_nonzero((np.power(10, 17) <= z1) & (z1 < np.power(10, 20.3))) * 1.0 / z1.size
LLS_covering_fraction_XZ = np.count_nonzero((np.power(10, 17) <= z2) & (z2 < np.power(10, 20.3))) * 1.0 / z2.size
LLS = np.sqrt(np.power(LLS_covering_fraction_XY, 2)+np.power(LLS_covering_fraction_YZ, 2)+np.power(LLS_covering_fraction_XZ, 2))/np.sqrt(3)
LLS_sigma = max([abs(LLS-LLS_covering_fraction_XY),abs(LLS-LLS_covering_fraction_YZ),abs(LLS-LLS_covering_fraction_XZ)])
DLA_covering_fraction_XY = np.count_nonzero(np.power(10, 20.3) <= z0) * 1.0 / z0.size
DLA_covering_fraction_YZ = np.count_nonzero(np.power(10, 20.3) <= z1) * 1.0 / z1.size
DLA_covering_fraction_XZ = np.count_nonzero(np.power(10, 20.3) <= z2) * 1.0 / z2.size
DLA = np.sqrt(np.power(DLA_covering_fraction_XY, 2)+np.power(DLA_covering_fraction_YZ, 2)+np.power(DLA_covering_fraction_XZ, 2))/np.sqrt(3)
DLA_sigma = max([abs(DLA-DLA_covering_fraction_XY),abs(DLA-DLA_covering_fraction_YZ),abs(DLA-DLA_covering_fraction_XZ)])


z0plot = plt.subplot(221)
plt.imshow(z0, vmin=0.0001+covering_fraction_z.min(), vmax=covering_fraction_z.max(), origin='lower',
           extent=[x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), y.max()],
                norm=colors.LogNorm())
plt.ylabel("Y [kpc]")
z0plot.set(aspect=1)


axparameters = plt.subplot(222)
frame = plt.gca()
frame.axes.get_xaxis().set_ticks([])
frame.axes.get_yaxis().set_ticks([])
axparameters.set(aspect=1)
plt.text(0.02, 0.2, 'LAF=%.5f$\pm$%.5f \n\n\n LLS=%.5f$\pm$%.5f \n\n\n DLA=%.5f$\pm$%.5f' % (LAF, LAF_sigma, LLS, LLS_sigma, DLA, DLA_sigma))
plt.colorbar()
plt.tight_layout()

z1plot = plt.subplot(223)
plt.imshow(z1, vmin=0.0001+covering_fraction_y.min(), vmax=covering_fraction_y.max(), origin='lower',
           extent=[x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), y.max()],
                norm=colors.LogNorm())
plt.xlabel("X [kpc]")
plt.ylabel("Z [kpc]") 
z1plot.set(aspect=1)



z2plot = plt.subplot(224)
plt.imshow(z2, vmin=0.0001+covering_fraction_x.min(), vmax=covering_fraction_x.max(), origin='lower',
           extent=[x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), y.max()],
                norm=colors.LogNorm())
plt.xlabel("Y [kpc]")
z2plot.set(aspect=1)


myfig = fig.Figure(figsize=(8, 8), dpi=900, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k', tight_layout=True)
plt.suptitle('HI Column Density Maps', size=20)
plt.tight_layout(rect=[0, 0, 1, 0.9])
plt.savefig('m11q.png', dpi=900)
plt.show()
```

Which produces the following map
[image: Original Code]

---

Here is the code written by Xevaquor as an answer to my original post:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-    
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.interpolate
#import matplotlib.figure as fig
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import matplotlib.colorbar as cb
import matplotlib.ticker as tk 
import pylab as pl
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
from matplotlib import gridspec

x, y, covering_fraction_z, covering_fraction_x, covering_fraction_y = np.genfromtxt(r'm11q.txt', unpack=True)

def fmt(x, pos):
    return '10e{}'.format(np.log10(x))

nInterp = 4300
xi, yi = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), nInterp), np.linspace(y.min(), y.max(), nInterp)
xi, yi = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)

z0 = scipy.interpolate.griddata((x, y), covering_fraction_z, (xi, yi), method='nearest')
z1 = scipy.interpolate.griddata((x, y), covering_fraction_x, (xi, yi), method='nearest')
z2 = scipy.interpolate.griddata((x, y), covering_fraction_y, (xi, yi), method='nearest')

LAF_covering_fraction_XY = np.count_nonzero((np.power(10, 14) <= z0) & (z0 < np.power(10, 17))) * 1.0 / z0.size
LAF_covering_fraction_YZ = np.count_nonzero((np.power(10, 14) <= z1) & (z1 < np.power(10, 17))) * 1.0 / z1.size
LAF_covering_fraction_XZ = np.count_nonzero((np.power(10, 14) <= z2) & (z2 < np.power(10, 17))) * 1.0 / z2.size
LAF = np.sqrt(np.power(LAF_covering_fraction_XY, 2)+np.power(LAF_covering_fraction_YZ, 2)+np.power(LAF_covering_fraction_XZ, 2))/np.sqrt(3)
LAF_sigma = max([abs(LAF-LAF_covering_fraction_XY),abs(LAF-LAF_covering_fraction_YZ),abs(LAF-LAF_covering_fraction_XZ)])
LLS_covering_fraction_XY = np.count_nonzero((np.power(10, 17) <= z0) & (z0 < np.power(10, 20.3))) * 1.0 / z0.size
LLS_covering_fraction_YZ = np.count_nonzero((np.power(10, 17) <= z1) & (z1 < np.power(10, 20.3))) * 1.0 / z1.size
LLS_covering_fraction_XZ = np.count_nonzero((np.power(10, 17) <= z2) & (z2 < np.power(10, 20.3))) * 1.0 / z2.size
LLS = np.sqrt(np.power(LLS_covering_fraction_XY, 2)+np.power(LLS_covering_fraction_YZ, 2)+np.power(LLS_covering_fraction_XZ, 2))/np.sqrt(3)
LLS_sigma = max([abs(LLS-LLS_covering_fraction_XY),abs(LLS-LLS_covering_fraction_YZ),abs(LLS-LLS_covering_fraction_XZ)])
DLA_covering_fraction_XY = np.count_nonzero(np.power(10, 20.3) <= z0) * 1.0 / z0.size
DLA_covering_fraction_YZ = np.count_nonzero(np.power(10, 20.3) <= z1) * 1.0 / z1.size
DLA_covering_fraction_XZ = np.count_nonzero(np.power(10, 20.3) <= z2) * 1.0 / z2.size
DLA = np.sqrt(np.power(DLA_covering_fraction_XY, 2)+np.power(DLA_covering_fraction_YZ, 2)+np.power(DLA_covering_fraction_XZ, 2))/np.sqrt(3)
DLA_sigma = max([abs(DLA-DLA_covering_fraction_XY),abs(DLA-DLA_covering_fraction_YZ),abs(DLA-DLA_covering_fraction_XZ)])


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))

gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 3, width_ratios=[5, 5, 1], height_ratios=[1,1,1]) 
ax0 = plt.subplot(gs[0])
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[3])
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs[4])

#cmap = colors.ListedColormap(['#ffdddd','#000000', '#ff9999', '#ff7777', '#ff5555', '#ff3333' ,'#ff1111'])
#'gray','green','pink','brown','blue','violet','yellow','orange', 
cmap = colors.ListedColormap(['#000000', 'gray','#ffdddd', '#ff9999', '#ff7777', '#ff5555', '#ff3333', '#ff1111', 'blue'])
boundaries = [np.power(10., 10), np.power(10., 11), np.power(10., 12), np.power(10., 13), np.power(10., 14), np.power(10., 15), np.power(10., 16), np.power(10.,17), np.power(10.,20.3), np.power(10.,25)]
norm = colors.BoundaryNorm(boundaries, cmap.N, clip=True)

pcmz0 = ax0.pcolormesh(xi, yi, z0, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
ax0.set_xticks([x.min(), x.max()])
ax0.set_yticks([y.min(), y.max()])
ax0.set_xlim([x.min(), x.max()])
ax0.set_ylim([y.min(), y.max()])
ax0.set(aspect=1)
pcmz1 = ax1.pcolormesh(xi, yi, z1, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
ax1.set_xticks([x.min(), x.max()])
ax1.set_yticks([y.min(), y.max()])
ax1.set_xlim([x.min(), x.max()])
ax1.set_ylim([y.min(), y.max()])
ax1.set(aspect=1)
pcmz2 = ax2.pcolormesh(xi, yi, z2, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
ax2.set_xticks([x.min(), x.max()])
ax2.set_yticks([y.min(), y.max()])
ax2.set_xlim([x.min(), x.max()])
ax2.set_ylim([y.min(), y.max()])
ax2.set(aspect=1)

axparameters = plt.subplot(gs[1])
frame = plt.gca()
frame.axes.get_xaxis().set_ticks([])
frame.axes.get_yaxis().set_ticks([])
axparameters.set(aspect=1)
plt.text(0.1, 0.2, 'LAF=%.5f$\pm$%.5f \n\n\n LLS=%.5f$\pm$%.5f \n\n\n DLA=%.5f$\pm$%.5f' % (LAF, LAF_sigma, LLS, LLS_sigma, DLA, DLA_sigma), size=10)


axc = plt.subplot(gs[:,2])
plt.colorbar(pcmz1,  cax=axc,format=ticker.FuncFormatter(fmt))

ax0.set_ylabel("Y [kpc]")  
ax1.set_xlabel("X [kpc]")
ax1.set_ylabel("Z [kpc]") 
ax2.set_xlabel("Y [kpc]") 
fig.suptitle('HI Column Density Maps', size=20)
gs.tight_layout(fig, rect=[0, 0, 1, 0.9])
plt.savefig('m11q.png', dpi=900)
plt.show()
```

Which produces the following maps:
[image: Xevaquor's Code]

---

And here is the final version of the code which does everything I aimed for except few caveats mentioned inside the answer (by me) to the post:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.interpolate
#import matplotlib.figure as fig
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import matplotlib.colorbar as cb
import matplotlib.ticker as tk 
import pylab as pl
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
from matplotlib import gridspec

x, y, covering_fraction_z, covering_fraction_x, covering_fraction_y = np.genfromtxt(r'm11q.txt', unpack=True)

def fmt(x, pos):
    return '10e{}'.format(np.log10(x))

nInterp = 3000
xi, yi = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), nInterp), np.linspace(y.min(), y.max(), nInterp)
xi, yi = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)

z0 = scipy.interpolate.griddata((x, y), covering_fraction_z, (xi, yi), method='nearest')
z1 = scipy.interpolate.griddata((x, y), covering_fraction_x, (xi, yi), method='nearest')
z2 = scipy.interpolate.griddata((x, y), covering_fraction_y, (xi, yi), method='nearest')


Pixel_Smoothing_Scale = 0.497
Halo_Pixels_No = (x.max()-x.min())*(y.max()-y.min())/ np.power(Pixel_Smoothing_Scale, 2)
DLA_Pixels_No_xy, DLA_Pixels_No_yz, DLA_Pixels_No_xz = 0, 0, 0
LLS_Pixels_No_xy, LLS_Pixels_No_yz, LLS_Pixels_No_xz = 0, 0, 0
LAF_Pixels_No_xy, LAF_Pixels_No_yz, LAF_Pixels_No_xz = 0, 0, 0

for i in np.arange(0, np.size(x)):
    if covering_fraction_z[i] >= np.power(10., 20.3):
        DLA_Pixels_No_xy+=1
    if ((covering_fraction_z[i] >= np.power(10., 17)) & (covering_fraction_z[i] < np.power(10., 20.3))):
        LLS_Pixels_No_xy+=1   
    if ((covering_fraction_z[i] >= np.power(10., 14)) & (covering_fraction_z[i] < np.power(10., 17))):
        LAF_Pixels_No_xy+=1    
    if covering_fraction_x[i] >= np.power(10., 20.3):
        DLA_Pixels_No_yz+=1
    if ((covering_fraction_x[i] >= np.power(10., 17)) & (covering_fraction_x[i] < np.power(10., 20.3))):
        LLS_Pixels_No_yz+=1 
    if ((covering_fraction_x[i] >= np.power(10., 14)) & (covering_fraction_x[i] < np.power(10., 17))):
        LAF_Pixels_No_yz+=1    
    if covering_fraction_y[i] >= np.power(10., 20.3):
        DLA_Pixels_No_xz+=1
    if ((covering_fraction_y[i] >= np.power(10., 17)) & (covering_fraction_y[i] < np.power(10., 20.3))):
        LLS_Pixels_No_xz+=1 
    if ((covering_fraction_y[i] >= np.power(10., 14)) & (covering_fraction_y[i] < np.power(10., 17))):
        LAF_Pixels_No_xz+=1

DLA_covering_fraction_XY, DLA_covering_fraction_YZ, DLA_covering_fraction_XZ = DLA_Pixels_No_xy/Halo_Pixels_No, DLA_Pixels_No_yz/Halo_Pixels_No, DLA_Pixels_No_xz/Halo_Pixels_No
DLA = np.sqrt(np.power(DLA_covering_fraction_XY, 2)+np.power(DLA_covering_fraction_YZ, 2)+np.power(DLA_covering_fraction_XZ, 2))/np.sqrt(3)
DLA_sigma = max([abs(DLA-DLA_covering_fraction_XY),abs(DLA-DLA_covering_fraction_YZ),abs(DLA-DLA_covering_fraction_XZ)])

LLS_covering_fraction_XY, LLS_covering_fraction_YZ, LLS_covering_fraction_XZ = LLS_Pixels_No_xy/Halo_Pixels_No, LLS_Pixels_No_yz/Halo_Pixels_No, LLS_Pixels_No_xz/Halo_Pixels_No
LLS = np.sqrt(np.power(LLS_covering_fraction_XY, 2)+np.power(LLS_covering_fraction_YZ, 2)+np.power(LLS_covering_fraction_XZ, 2))/np.sqrt(3)
LLS_sigma = max([abs(LLS-LLS_covering_fraction_XY),abs(LLS-LLS_covering_fraction_YZ),abs(LLS-LLS_covering_fraction_XZ)])

LAF_covering_fraction_XY, LAF_covering_fraction_YZ, LAF_covering_fraction_XZ = LAF_Pixels_No_xy/Halo_Pixels_No, LAF_Pixels_No_yz/Halo_Pixels_No, LAF_Pixels_No_xz/Halo_Pixels_No
LAF = np.sqrt(np.power(LAF_covering_fraction_XY, 2)+np.power(LAF_covering_fraction_YZ, 2)+np.power(LAF_covering_fraction_XZ, 2))/np.sqrt(3)
LAF_sigma = max([abs(LAF-LAF_covering_fraction_XY),abs(LAF-LAF_covering_fraction_YZ),abs(LAF-LAF_covering_fraction_XZ)])




fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))

gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 3, width_ratios=[5, 5, 1], height_ratios=[1,1,1]) 
ax0 = plt.subplot(gs[0])
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[3])
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs[4])

#cmap = colors.ListedColormap(['#ffdddd','#000000', '#ff9999', '#ff7777', '#ff5555', '#ff3333' ,'#ff1111'])
#'gray','green','pink','brown','blue','violet','yellow','orange', 
cmap = colors.ListedColormap(['#ffdddd', '#ff7777', '#ff3333', 'yellow', 'orange','green', 'red', 'blue'])
boundaries = [np.power(10., 4), np.power(10., 6), np.power(10., 8), np.power(10., 10), np.power(10., 12), np.power(10., 14), np.power(10.,17), np.power(10.,20.3), np.power(10.,25)]
norm = colors.BoundaryNorm(boundaries, cmap.N, clip=True)

pcmz0 = ax0.pcolormesh(xi, yi, z0, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
ax0.set_xticks([x.min(), x.max()])
ax0.set_yticks([y.min(), y.max()])
ax0.set_xlim([x.min(), x.max()])
ax0.set_ylim([y.min(), y.max()])
ax0.set(aspect=1)
pcmz1 = ax1.pcolormesh(xi, yi, z1, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
ax1.set_xticks([x.min(), x.max()])
ax1.set_yticks([y.min(), y.max()])
ax1.set_xlim([x.min(), x.max()])
ax1.set_ylim([y.min(), y.max()])
ax1.set(aspect=1)
pcmz2 = ax2.pcolormesh(xi, yi, z2, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
ax2.set_xticks([x.min(), x.max()])
ax2.set_yticks([y.min(), y.max()])
ax2.set_xlim([x.min(), x.max()])
ax2.set_ylim([y.min(), y.max()])
ax2.set(aspect=1)

axparameters = plt.subplot(gs[1])
frame = plt.gca()
frame.axes.get_xaxis().set_ticks([])
frame.axes.get_yaxis().set_ticks([])
axparameters.set(aspect=1)
plt.text(0.1, 0.2, 'LAF=%.6f$\pm$%.6f \n\n\n LLS=%.6f$\pm$%.6f \n\n\n DLA=%.6f$\pm$%.6f' % (LAF, LAF_sigma, LLS, LLS_sigma, DLA, DLA_sigma), size=9)


axc = plt.subplot(gs[:,2])
plt.colorbar(pcmz1,  cax=axc,format=ticker.FuncFormatter(fmt))

ax0.set_ylabel("Y [kpc]")  
ax1.set_xlabel("X [kpc]")
ax1.set_ylabel("Z [kpc]") 
ax2.set_xlabel("Y [kpc]") 
fig.suptitle('HI Column Density Maps', size=20)
gs.tight_layout(fig, rect=[0, 0, 1, 0.9])
plt.savefig('m11q.png', dpi=900)
plt.show()
```

which produces the following maps:
[image: Final Version of the Maps]

Comment: Could you share txt file?

Comment: @Xevaquor, Thanks for asking for the file. I added it within the text under the name m11q.txt as a link on pastin website. Sincerely,

Comment: @Xevaquor Thanks, probably I will find some to answer in next few hours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) and (2) are related. You can define custom color scheme. For discrite arbitrary values it can be eg:

```
cmap = colors.ListedColormap(['red', '#000000','#444444', '#666666', '#ffffff', 'blue', 'orange'])
boundaries = [-1, -0.9, -0.6, -0.3, 0, 0.3, 0.6, 1]
norm = colors.BoundaryNorm(boundaries, cmap.N, clip=True)
```

This will map values following way:

- -1.0 x < -0.9 to red
- -0.9 < x < -0.6 to black (#000000)
- -0.6 < x < -0.3 to #444444
- and so on

Color i will be used for values between boundary i and i+1. Colors can be specified by names ('red', 'green'), HTML codes ('#ffaa44', '#441188') or RGB tuples ((0.2, 0.9, 0.45)).

Complete example:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-    
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.interpolate
#import matplotlib.figure as fig
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import matplotlib.colorbar as cb
import matplotlib.ticker as tk 
import pylab as pl
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
from matplotlib import gridspec

x, y, covering_fraction_z, covering_fraction_x, covering_fraction_y = np.genfromtxt(r'm11q.txt', unpack=True)

def fmt(x, pos):
    return '10e{}'.format(np.log10(x))

nInterp = 402
xi, yi = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), nInterp), np.linspace(y.min(), y.max(), nInterp)
xi, yi = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)

z0 = scipy.interpolate.griddata((x, y), covering_fraction_z, (xi, yi), method='nearest')
z1 = scipy.interpolate.griddata((x, y), covering_fraction_x, (xi, yi), method='nearest')
z2 = scipy.interpolate.griddata((x, y), covering_fraction_y, (xi, yi), method='nearest')

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))

gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 3, width_ratios=[4, 4, 1], height_ratios=[1,1,1]) 
ax0 = plt.subplot(gs[0])
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[3])
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs[4])

cmap = colors.ListedColormap(['#ffdddd','#000000', '#ff9999', '#ff7777', '#ff5555', '#ff3333' ,'#ff1111'])
boundaries = [np.power(10., 14), np.power(10., 15.5), np.power(10.,17), np.power(10.,20.3), np.power(10.,25)]
norm = colors.BoundaryNorm(boundaries, cmap.N, clip=True)

pcmz0 = ax0.pcolormesh(xi, yi, z0, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
ax0.set_xticks([x.min(), x.max()]) #arbitrary, also for Y axis ticks
ax0.set_xlim([x.min(), x.max()])
ax0.set_ylim([y.min(), y.max()])
pcmz1 = ax1.pcolormesh(xi, yi, z1, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
ax1.set_xticks([x.min(), x.max()])
ax1.set_xlim([x.min(), x.max()])
ax1.set_ylim([y.min(), y.max()])
pcmz2 = ax2.pcolormesh(xi, yi, z2, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
ax2.set_xticks([x.min(), x.max()])
ax2.set_xlim([x.min(), x.max()])
ax2.set_ylim([y.min(), y.max()])

axc = plt.subplot(gs[:,2])
plt.colorbar(pcmz1,  cax=axc,format=ticker.FuncFormatter(fmt))

ax0.set_ylabel("Y [kpc]")  
ax1.set_xlabel("X [kpc]")
ax1.set_ylabel("Z [kpc]") 
ax2.set_xlabel("Y [kpc]")   
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('m11q.png', dpi=900)
plt.show()
```

For (3). There are many ways to do this. For example:

```
fraction = np.count_nonzero((np.power(10, 14) <= Z) & (Z < np.power(10, 15.5)) * 1.0 / Z.size
```

will give you fraction of values in range [10e14, 10e15.5)

(4) depends on method of creating subplots. With `GridSpec` it won't appear if you do not declare it explicitly.

Comment: Yes, thanks Xevaquor. This is exactly what I am after. However, after matching my plots with yours I came to the conclusion that it would be better to show those "red" colors on the maps and colorbar as different colors.  Instead of all being from red family, I guess I have to choose other colors that are clearer and better convey the pattern. So, is that possible to actually choose blue for the highest level and red for the next to the highest level and then orange for the third one and finally yellow for the lowest contour? Btw, your version is way faster than mine which is impressive.

Comment: Also my understanding is that lower values for nInterp makes the code faster but in the expense of losing resolution and detailed information. Right? I don't know if any other reason could be the cause.

Comment: I just added both versions of the map to the original post. The upper map is produced by my original code (including ALL data and not just the ones pasted in the post) and the lower one is produced by your code (again including ALL data and not just the ones pasted in the post). As you can see there are more substructures evident in mine yet hidden in yours. This is fine and understandable given the fact that we want a cut on the lower boundary of the colorbar which is conveyed correctly in your code. It is amazing that high density regions are so similar though which is what I care about.

Comment: Hopefully all this now will help us to answer the questions. Due to my low rate on this website, unfortunately I am not able to press "This answer is useful" and I hope soon I will press that once I get some reputation but I promise I will accept the answer as the correct one after we made our best progress in answering the questions. Even if it proves that we cannot get those answers, I still believe that it is legitimate and mandatory to accept your answer. Again, I really thank you for your time and helpfulness.

Comment: @ Xevaquor, I just edited the post including your code and its output with some modification of colors. I also updated the questions originally asked. The color issue is resolved but I am having problem with the covering fractions as you can see your updated code now just below my code in the post.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer to the updated version of the question. Originally I was not able to produce a color bar for my maps. Xevaquor helped me with that by the above answer. So, the answer was legitimately posted by Xevaquor and it is marked as "the answer" now. However, as I was taking my time to resolve some of the issues with covering fractions, finally I was able to understand the problem mathematically and then try to approach it numerically in a python code. My issue was that I did not realize that what I am after is in fact a ratio of the number of pixels. This is why, I had to count the number of pixels that lie inside a range of column densities and then divide that by the total number of pixels making each projection of the map. Since the smoothing scale is known to be $0.497 kpc$, we know that total number of pixels will be the physical area of the map in $kpc^{2}$ divided by the area of each pixel namely $0.497^{2}$. So, the following snippet of code can be added to the original and/or Xevaquor's code to account for the covering fractions correctly:

```
Pixel_Smoothing_Scale = 0.497
Halo_Pixels_No = (x.max()-x.min())*(y.max()-y.min())/ np.power(Pixel_Smoothing_Scale, 2)
DLA_Pixels_No_xy, DLA_Pixels_No_yz, DLA_Pixels_No_xz = 0, 0, 0
LLS_Pixels_No_xy, LLS_Pixels_No_yz, LLS_Pixels_No_xz = 0, 0, 0

for i in np.arange(0, np.size(x)):
    if covering_fraction_z[i] >= np.power(10., 20.3):
        DLA_Pixels_No_xy+=1
    if ((covering_fraction_z[i] >= np.power(10., 17)) & (covering_fraction_z[i] < np.power(10., 20.3))):
        LLS_Pixels_No_xy+=1   
    if covering_fraction_x[i] >= np.power(10., 20.3):
        DLA_Pixels_No_yz+=1
    if ((covering_fraction_x[i] >= np.power(10., 17)) & (covering_fraction_x[i] < np.power(10., 20.3))):
        LLS_Pixels_No_yz+=1 
    if covering_fraction_y[i] >= np.power(10., 20.3):
        DLA_Pixels_No_xz+=1
    if ((covering_fraction_y[i] >= np.power(10., 17)) & (covering_fraction_y[i] < np.power(10., 20.3))):
        LLS_Pixels_No_xz+=1 

DLA_covering_fraction_XY, DLA_covering_fraction_YZ, DLA_covering_fraction_XZ = DLA_Pixels_No_xy/Halo_Pixels_No, DLA_Pixels_No_yz/Halo_Pixels_No, DLA_Pixels_No_xz/Halo_Pixels_No
DLA = np.sqrt(np.power(DLA_covering_fraction_XY, 2)+np.power(DLA_covering_fraction_YZ, 2)+np.power(DLA_covering_fraction_XZ, 2))/np.sqrt(3)
DLA_sigma = max([abs(DLA-DLA_covering_fraction_XY),abs(DLA-DLA_covering_fraction_YZ),abs(DLA-DLA_covering_fraction_XZ)])

LLS_covering_fraction_XY, LLS_covering_fraction_YZ, LLS_covering_fraction_XZ = LLS_Pixels_No_xy/Halo_Pixels_No, LLS_Pixels_No_yz/Halo_Pixels_No, LLS_Pixels_No_xz/Halo_Pixels_No
LLS = np.sqrt(np.power(LLS_covering_fraction_XY, 2)+np.power(LLS_covering_fraction_YZ, 2)+np.power(LLS_covering_fraction_XZ, 2))/np.sqrt(3)
LLS_sigma = max([abs(LLS-LLS_covering_fraction_XY),abs(LLS-LLS_covering_fraction_YZ),abs(LLS-LLS_covering_fraction_XZ)])

print(Pixel_Smoothing_Scale)
print(LLS_covering_fraction_XY, LLS_covering_fraction_YZ, LLS_covering_fraction_XZ)
print(DLA_covering_fraction_XY, DLA_covering_fraction_YZ, DLA_covering_fraction_XZ)
```

---

With this being said, the only issue that is unresolved is the slowness of the code for some files that are huge and that increasing `interp` value cannot be continued indefinitely towards larger values in order to get smoother maps. So, I don't know how to approach this problem in order to make smoother maps (colors be filled homogeneously and no single region on the map be devoid of any color) without making the code increasingly slow. Any help towards this issue is appreciated.